# PHP Script that converts strong to Salted MD5

Tags: php

Im not sure if this is ok, see, Im not very familiar with PHP so I wonder if anyone can let me borrow a script that converts strings to Salted MD5 (The one Joomla uses for password in the database).

I hope to convert multiple lines in 1 go. I'm adding hundreds of user in Joomla so adding them directly in database is much faster.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Joomla 3.2+ uses Bcrypt, not MD5 ;)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to be 100% is to import users and generate passwords with:

```
        $password = JUserHelper::genRandomPassword();
        $params = array(
                        'name' => $name,
                        'username' => $username,
                        'email' => $email,
                        'password' => $password,
                        'password2' => $password
                        'groups' => array(2),
                        'sendEmail' => 0,
                        'block' => 0
        );
        $user = new JUser(0);
        $user->bind($params);
        $user->save();
```